# why shows IndexError: list index out of range for the code? if I change to len(A)-1 the code can work. why this happened?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
A= [i for i in str(2635384)]
for i in range(len(A),0,-1):
    print(A[i])
```

shows

> IndexError: list index out of range for the code

Whereas

```
A= [i for i in str(2635384)]
for i in range(len(A)-1,0,-1):
    print(A[i])
```

can run

Comment: The first element in `range(len(A),0,-1)` is `len(A)`, which is not a valid index for `A`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: I make the asumption that you use Python 3, where [*range()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) is a function which yields values instead of generating a list like in Python 2 (the equivalent function is [*xrange()*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) ).

The *range()* function is documented in the topic [Built-in Types —> Ranges](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range).

Quoting the documentation:

> The arguments to the range constructor must be integers (either built-in `int` or any object that implements the `__index__` special method). If the *step* argument is omitted, it defaults to 1. If the *start* argument is omitted, it defaults to 0. If *step* is zero, `ValueError` is raised.
>
> For a positive *step*, the contents of a range *r* are determined by the formula `r[i] = start + step*i` where `i >= 0` and `r[i] < stop`.
>
> For a negative *step*, the contents of the range are still determined by the formula `r[i] = start + step*i`, but the constraints are `i >= 0` and `r[i] > stop`.

With your example `range(len(A), 0, -1)`, you iterate from the value `len(A)` inclusive to `0` exclusive. Actually, [by convention in the Python language](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2013/10/why-python-uses-0-based-indexing.html) , the *start* index is inclusive and the *stop* index is exclusive. Ie.: in your case, your range will generate the indexes `len(A)`, `len(A) – 1`, ..., `2`, `1`; but it will never reach `0`.

This is the same rule for slicing. Given a list *L*, `L[a:b]` is the slice of *L* from index *a* inclusive to index *b* exclusive (so *b – 1*).

So, to answer your question, the index `len(A)` is out of range: only indexes from `0` to `len(A) – 1` are valid.

For your case, the best practice is to use [*reversed*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed), to iterate the sequence in reverse order:

```
for letter in reversed(str(2635384)):
    print(letter)
```

You get:

```
4
8
3
5
3
6
2
```

Comment: Thank you so much Laurent! it really helps me:)

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, you try to access the item at  index len(A), but len(A) equals 7, and the list index has a maximum of 6.

khelwood was pointing to that already.

Answer (score 0):

Why? 
Well, because list indexing in python is starting at zero and goes up to `len(<iterable>)-1`, that's why.

So trying to get `A[len(A)]` will always fail.

But when working with `range` i'd suggest you do a quick test in the python shell to see if everything is working as planned, for example:

```
for x in range(3,0,-1):
     print(x)
```

would present you the output:

```
3
2
1
```

This shows you what's going on. 
In this case we can clearly see that the first list element would not be used since the `0` is missing.

So, what you probably want is `range(len(A)-1,-1,-1)`.

Comment: Please, don’t use `list` as a variable name.  It’s a builtin function.

Answer (score 0):

```
A= [i for i in str(2635384)]

for i in range(len(A)-1,-1,-1):
    print(A[i])
```

This is what you want. ^

range(len(A),0,-1) iterates from 7 to 0 backwards, but since **Python list indexing starts at 0** instead of 1, you need to subtract 1 from both parameters of the range.

Giving you:

```
for i in range(len(A)-1,-1,-1):
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `range()` function, the first argument is always an index that exists in the list. If there is an array `A = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]` then `len(A)` would return `4` and the indexes would be `0, 1, 2, 3` so if you use `range(Len(A), 0, -1)` it would cause an error since 4 is out of range of the indexes in the list.

If you use `range(Len(A) - 1, 0, -1)` then the output would be `"d", "c", "b"` and "a" would not be included in the output since the range goes to `0` and in the range function the range ends at 1 value before the second argument.

So simply put, for `range(3, 0, -1)` the indexes are `3, 2, 1` and for `range(0, 3, 1)` the indexes are `0, 1, 2`. The `range()` function stops 1 value before the second argument.